# Thread throws error while checking a database

Tags: c++, mysql, database, multithreading

Below is some code I wrote for a function that is supposed to always be running on its own thread checking a database for new information and appending the new information to global vectors. The issue I seem to be having is that after so many times around, all being successful, I will spontaneously get this error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x5B46F1F9 (libmysql.dll) in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000003B0.`

not too sure whats up but it seems to happen right after the `if(connect){}` statement because right as it crashes i see the printed statement of `Connection Failed!`. I just dont have a reason as to why that would fail. I had a similar issue that was caused by reaching the max number of connections to the database but i dont see how this would happen because after every itteration of the `if` statement i use the `mysql_close(connect)` statement.

```
void getNewFromDB(){
while(globalExit == false){
     MYSQL *connect; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
    connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
    /* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
    if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"MySQL Initialization Failed");


    }
    /* Now we will actually connect to the specific database.*/

    connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
    /* Following if statements are unneeded too, but it's worth it to show on your
    first app, so that if your database is empty or the query didn't return anything it
    will at least let you know that the connection to the mysql server was established. */

    if(connect){
       printf("Connection Succeeded\n");
    }
    else{
       printf("Connection Failed!\n");
    }


        MYSQL_RES *result; /* Create a pointer to recieve the return value.*/
        MYSQL_ROW row;  /* Assign variable for rows. */

        mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM locationTime ORDER BY id DESC");
        /* Send a query to the database. */

        result = mysql_store_result(connect); /* Receive the result and store it in res_set */

        unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(result); /* Create the count to print all rows */

        row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
        if(row[0] > ids.back()){
            ids.push_back(row[0]);
            dateTime.push_back(row[1]);
            locs.push_back(setLocation(row[2]));
            imgPaths.push_back(row[3]);
        }
mysql_close(connect);
    }
       /* Close and shutdown */

}
```

**EDIT:** All of the given answers fix part of the issue, and I thank you. But now what I don't understand is why after 16 thousand some request would all of a sudden the connection fail?

Comment: That's very likely a `null`-pointer AV. Maybe one of your arguments in one of your MySQL-calls is not allowed to be `null`? The most likely suspect is `connect` in `mysql_query(connect,...)`

Comment: Whether `mysql_real_connect` succeeds or fails you still trudge on. All the code should be moved into the `if(connect)` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 MYSQL *connect; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
/* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
{
    fprintf(stderr,"MySQL Initialization Failed");
}
```

After that part of code, with message about failing, your "connect" is not initialized, so you receive access violation because you put "connect" to function. Without initialization, it can point to any part of your virtual memory. That is why you have problem.

Fix it this way:

```
 MYSQL *connect = NULL; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
/* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
{
    fprintf(stderr,"MySQL Initialization Failed");
    return;
}
```

Also you should use standart way of your library to print error number and error reason, to understand what happens.
Use:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(connect));
```

UPD: Also you may have memory leak:

```
connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
```

So, you never free your connect object that was received from

```
connect=mysql_init(NULL);
```

line. You just owerwrite your pointer to it by pointer to connection that returns by mysql_real_connect.

That is why, after 16k of success, you may fail because of lack of memory to allocate. [It](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) tells that returning pointer points to copy of first parameter.

Comment: All of the given answers fix part of the issue, and I thank you. But now what I don't understand is why after 16 thousand some request would all of a sudden the connection fail?

Comment: I updated answer. MSSQL, as pointed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-init.html, can return NULL if has problems with memory. Also it has to be freed by mysql_close(), but you don't do it.

Comment: I do close the Connect variable with the mysql_close(connect); statement right before all of the closing brackets. Is this close statement out if place?

Comment: No. You close connection that you received from mysql_real_connect there.

Comment: And you never close connection that you received from mysql_init

Comment: Ok so them how would I go about closing that, I was just under the impression that the MySQL_close(connection); cleaned it all up. So where would I need to put a close statement and with what syntax to properly have all of that closed and cleaned up for the next pass?

Comment: As I wrote above: save result of mysql_real_connect not to "connect" but to second MYSQL* pointer (for example "connect2"), and then free both pointers, connect and connect2. Try it at least.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that would do because then would that not be the exact same thing as just having the one `connect` pointer? I did try it and it gave me this error    `Unhandled exception at 0x5A2FD532 (libmysql.dll) in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.`

Comment: This ended up being very close to the total issue, I added a `Sleep(185);` and this stopped it from crashing/losing connection. It must have eventually (after a large number of 16k requests) over whelmed the server. The server it was requesting from was only an XAMPP server after all. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome :-) I had suggestion that function returns copy of first connection, that is why I asked you to try to close both connections. I guess timeout is not good solution, if that happens by server's issue, you should correctly parse it on your side.

Answer (score 0):

If connect is false, you print "Connection failed", but after that you use the invalid connect object anyway in the query call.